# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

This is the first time I have tried writing an Oracle procedure and I am getting an error (shown in the question title) centering on the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` line.

I read online that it can only hand back `VARCAHR2` columns, so I have cast the only two non `VARCHAR2` columns that are being accessed, but I am still getting the error. This error is happening when I try to run it directly in the oracle SQL Developer.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOGGING_PRC 
(
  STARTDATE_IN IN VARCHAR2,
  ENDDATE_IN IN VARCHAR2,
  NAMES_IN IN VARCHAR2, 
  MODS_IN IN VARCHAR2, 
  LOGS_IN IN VARCHAR2,

  ID_OUT OUT VARCHAR2,
  NAME_OUT OUT VARCHAR2,
  MODULE_OUT OUT VARCHAR2,
  ENTRYDATE_OUT OUT VARCHAR2,
  STATUS_OUT OUT VARCHAR2,
  TYPE_OUT OUT VARCHAR2
)  
  AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT
    CAST(ID_LOG AS VARCHAR2(16)),
     APNAME,
     APPMOD,
     CAST(ENTRYDATE AS VARCHAR2(30)),
     APPSTATUS,
     LOGTYPE
  INTO 
      ID_OUT,
      NAME_OUT,
      MODULE_OUT,
      ENTRYDATE_OUT,
      STATUS_OUT,
      TYPE_OUT
   FROM 
     BASE          
   WHERE     
     ENTRYDATE > STARTDATE_IN AND
     ENTRYDATE  < ENDDATE_IN AND
     (NAMES  =  NAMES_IN OR NAMES_IN IS NULL) AND
     (MODS = MODS_IN OR MODS_IN IS NULL) AND
     (LOGS = LOGS_IN  OR LOGS_IN IS NULL);      
  RETURN;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ID_OUT, NAME_OUT, MODULE_OUT, ENTRYDATE_OUT, STATUS_OUT, TYPE_OUT);
END LOGGING_PRC;
```

Does someone see where I have the incorrect code?

Comment: The [syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_output.htm#ARPLS67327) shows it only takes a single string argument, not a list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE is defined as follows

```
procedure put_line(a varchar2);
```

so, it only accepts one input parameter.

If you need to print the values of more than one field, you need to concatenate them in a single `varchar2`; you can try with :

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ID_OUT || ',' || NAME_OUT || ',' || MODULE_OUT || ',' || ENTRYDATE_OUT || ',' || STATUS_OUT || ',' || TYPE_OUT);
```